# SEO: Split pages up or combine into one?

Tags: seo

I have a hypothetical SEO question. Let's say I was going to list out coupon codes for 50 different products on my website. For SEO purposes, would it be better to have 1 page that lists our all 50 coupon codes, or 1 page for each coupon code (i.e. 50 pages).

I'm leaning toward giving each coupon code its own page, so I can have unique  tags for each. It seems like this would be better for my search rankings. Anyone care to disagree? Any other thoughts on this or general guidelines for combining vs. splitting up pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by having one page for all the codes. When you see that one code generates enough traffic/content then make it it's own page.

Comment: I tend to agree with Sam, besides a page with so little content is unlikely to rank higher than a page with all those codes listed, I would say